# Display comments to user while executing Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to display comments to user while executing a procedure in a package. My package has 3 procedures. I am calling each one after other. I want to display **comments** on console like procedure xyz is executing, procedure executed successfully. I added comments inside procedure like `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCEDURE EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY')` but didn't worked for me. 
FYI i am using oracle 11g in windows 7 system.

Comment: what do you call "console" ? Sql plus ? Something else ? What's the environment where user should see the comments ?

Comment: Sorry for that DIsplay in SQLPLUS(when i execute package)

Comment: See for some suggestions this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523949/have-pl-sql-outputs-in-real-time/2643269

Answer (score 10):

You can't use `DBMS_OUTPUT` to display information on a procedure while it is running. This is because [`DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_output.htm#i1000105) doesn't display data on screen, rather, the data is put in a queue that is later read by the calling client (This queue is also invisible outside of its transaction). If you use `SQL*Plus` the queue is read and displayed automatically at the end of the procedure if you have `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`.

Other means exist to follow the progress of a procedure while it is running:

- You could [write to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453538/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-dbms-output-put-line-to-a-file) instead. [`UTL_FILE.put_line`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#i997640) will write directly if the parameter `autoflush` is set to true.
- You could set session variables with [`DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_appinf.htm#CHECEIEB). These variables can be read with another session by querying [`v$session`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3016.htm#i1414383).
- You could use [`AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTIONS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335331/autonomous-transaction/1335428#1335428) to log progress information in a dedicated table. This table can be queried by another session simultaneously.

As you can see you would need another process to read the information while it is written. In some applications, this would be achieved by running the main batch job in a new separate process, for example by calling [`DBMS_JOB`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD) or [`DBMS_SCHEDULER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI) while the calling transaction loops on the progress table or file until the job is complete.

SQL*Plus is not an interactive client, you will need some more sophisticated environment to achieve this functionality.

Comment: How to use DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO comments. could you give me an example.

Comment: See this [answer on another related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1523970/119634)