# Show message right after command show in code

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I have some procedure in PL/SQL like:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  p_data          DATE;
  v_line          VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  v_line := 'START';
  dbms_output.put_line (v_line);

---------- 1 --------------------------
  WRT.TL_XTERN.process(
      p_data_d => p_data_d
  );
  v_line := ' WRT.TL_XTERN.process ended';
  dbms_output.put_line (v_line);

---------- 2 --------------------------   
  WRT.TL_MAP.process(
      p_data_d => p_data_d
  );
  v_line := ' WRT.TL_MAP.process ended';
  dbms_output.put_line (v_line);

  v_line := 'STOP';
  dbms_output.put_line (v_line);      
END;
/
```

Now, when I run it in sqlplus, all messages appear after both process ended. 
How can I get each message exactly when it appears in code.

Comment: No possible. This is how `dbms_output` works. You can't change that

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of thing?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729739/oracle-pl-sql-tips-for-immediate-output-console-printing

Comment: @WilliamRobertson cool, thank you. It's going to help:)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, it also helped:)